# Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause - Mysql 5.7.10 - derived_merge not working

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
update tblwerknemerdienst toUpdate
set datumtot = (select subdate(datumvanaf,1)
    from (select * from tblwerknemerdienst) nextDienst
    where nextDienst.Werknemer = toUpdate.Werknemer
    and nextDienst.datumvanaf > toUpdate.DatumVanaf
    order by DatumVanaf
    LIMIT 1)
WHERE DatumTot IS NULL;
```

The query runs fine on MySql versions other than MySql 5.7.10. I've searched around the web and found that you have to set derived_merge=off, but sadly this had no effect and the query still fails with the same error.
I have also tried several different ways of rewriting the query, but all to no avail.
Is there something I'm missing or is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I fixed this by rewriting the whole thing in a procedure, where I used a cursor to execute the query and get the necessary data. Then I perform the update statement based upon the fields selected in the cursor.

This seemed to be the only way to reliably perform the operation required on different versions of MySql.